# To What Extent is the Fourier Inversion Theorem Due to the Self-Adjointedness of the Laplacian

Tags: fourier-analysis, spectral-theory, laplacian

I've tried looking this up (I looked at various spectral theorems) but couldn't find anything that talks about the connection between Fourier transforms and the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian (we may stick to $1$-D if it doesn't make a difference). Of course this stuff is used all the time in quantum mechanics, and I've seen the proof of Fourier inversion for $L^2$ in analysis, but nothing about spectral theory is mentioned. So can we say that Fourier inversion holds on $L^2$ due to the fact that the Laplacian is self-adjoint (well, I guess it's not everywhere defined, and maybe isn't quite self-adjoint, but maybe if we use a Sobolev space)?

Comment: The Laplacian is defined on manifolds which may not be groups. The Fourier transform is defined on nice functions out of topological groups which may not be manifolds. There is intersection, but neither envelops the other. As I understand it, Fourier inversion is a consequence of character orthogonality. That the eigenfunctions of $\Delta$ are in fact characters in $1$D is useful - one can use it to show $\Delta$ is self-adjoint (which to my mind means we're applying Fourier theory to Laplacians, rather than conversely), but are they still characters in higher dimensions?

Comment: @blue Hm, well the only things I know about characters are what I have read on Wikipedia, though it seems as if some of the eigenfunctions, namely the complex exponentials, are characters. It seems that you can give a quick proof that the trigonometric functions are dense in $L^2[a,b]$ by using the compact spectral theorem and the fact that the Laplacian is self-adjoint with Dirichlet BCs, which is why it seems like it might be similar for the Fourier transform.  Also it is quite easy to show that $\Delta$ is self-adjoint with integration by parts so the other way around seems more appealing.

Comment: Re: "the other way around," how do we use $\Delta$'s self-adjointness to explain Fourier inversion? I am not exactly clear on that.

Comment: @blue I meant it would be appealing if you could use the self-adjointness do explain it. As I said you can use it to prove that $e^{inx}$ are complete on compact sets, and that's basically a discrete Fourier transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. The Fourier transform and its inverse implement the Spectral Theorem for the selfadjoint operator $Af = \frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}f$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$ consisting of absolutely continuous $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ for which $f'\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. The spectral measure $E$ is
$$
  E[a,b]f = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{a}^{b}e^{isx}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-ist}\,dt\,ds   = (\chi_{[a,b]}f^{\wedge})^{\vee}.
$$
For a general Borel subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$, the spectral measure is $E(S)f = (\chi_{S}f^{\wedge})^{\vee}$. The one-dimensional Laplacian is the square of $A$:
$$
        -\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}f = A^{2}f
                   = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^{2}dE(t)f=(t^{2}f^{\wedge})^{\vee}.
$$
It is not terribly difficult to use the Spectral Theorem to derive these facts, to derive the Fourier transform $\vee$ and its inverse $\wedge$, and to show that $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are isometric inverses. One can show that $f \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ iff $sf^{\wedge}(s)\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. That is, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}s^{2}|f^{\wedge}(s)|^{2}\,ds < \infty$ iff $f \in L^{2}$ is absolutely continuous with $f' \in L^{2}$. I assume that's basically what you had in mind?